# Converting Excel #:## to String

Tags: excel, vb.net, format

I have an excel file that has values copied into it in the format:

```
      A
1    0:01
2    0:02
3    1:01
4    1:00
```

Which i need to convert to (in VB.net):

```
     A    B
1    0    1
2    0    2
3    1    1
4    1    0
```

The problem I have is that excel sees this value (#:##) as a time and i cant seem to turn it into a string for me to separate.

What I have tried:

```
xlsApp.ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "@"
```

I've tried changing the format of the cell before copying it to another but whatever i have tried the result always ends up being a decimal number.

Been struggling with this all day so if anyone could point me in the rite direction i would appreciate it.

Comment: The internal time format is fractions of a day (1 corresponds to 24 hours). You must work with this and extract 'hours' and 'minutes' from this.

Comment: Hi @Stefan thanks for the reply, I'm not quite sure what you mean. This number doesn't actually relate to a time at all but excel is assuming its a time format. In VB.net i cant seem to take the value of A1 because it sees the value as 0.000694444444444444.

Comment: Look at the functions [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/hour.php) and use `Hour` and `Minute` to separate the time into it's component parts.

Comment: try `xlsApp.ActiveCell.text` to get the string